# Reporting Services WinForms Security Permissions

Tags: .net, winforms, rdlc

I'm retrieving the following error while trying to execute a WinForms RDLC report from an obfuscated exe:

```
Failed to load expression host assembly. Details: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.
```

I have all the required dlls:

```
Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll
Microsoft.ReportViewer.DataVisualization.dll
Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel.dll
Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll
Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.resources.dll
Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll
```

If I try to execute the report from an unobfuscated exe it works fine, I tried with the dlls attached and unattached to the exe and it doesn't work.

I'm using .NET Framework 3.5 and RDLC Version 11.0.3452.

Comment: What exactly are you using to obfuscate your code? It clearly is the cause of your problem.

Comment: Hi, i´m using the obfuscator that windows provides